# Cant hide bottom navigation bar when using Parallax Scrolling Header with Tabs

Tags: android

I can't hide the navigation bar when I'm scrolling the wishlist, it always stays there.

[image]

Comment: Are you using recyclerview or listview?

Comment: i am using recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

```
 mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                if (dy > 0 && bottom_navigation.isShown()) {
                    bottom_navigation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else if (dy < 0 ) {
                    bottom_navigation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {

                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Where should i put it?? in the shop fragment or wishlist fragment??

Comment: please upvote if you think this is the desired solution.